# Can I get LuaLaTeX to do font variations on the Zapfino font just as XeLaTeX does?

Tags: luatex

When I use XeLateX on my mac I can get multiple variations for Zapfino like for example explained [here under Glyph Variants](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex). However this does not work when I run the same code though LuaLaTeX. Is there a way to get this functionality there as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you are on Mac OS X and using Apple shipped version of Zapfino, then the answer is no; this is an AAT font and LuaLaTeX does not support AAT features. There is however an [OpenType version of Zapfino](http://typophile.com/node/8122) by Linotype, it should work with LuaLaTeX (IIRC, Hans was using it as a benchmark while developing the OpenType code).

**Update**: here is an modified version of the aforementioned example to work with the OpenType font.

[image: output of the example below]

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% Dario Taraborelli (2008), Khaled Hosny (2011)
% The Beauty of LaTeX
% URL: http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex
% Some rights reserved: CC-BY-SA

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, fontspec, graphicx}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{.2,.5,1}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\color{red} #1}
\newcommand{\reda}[1]{\fontspec[Color=red,Variant=2]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\redb}[1]{\fontspec[Color=red,Variant=3]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\redc}[1]{\fontspec[Color=red,Variant=4]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\redd}[1]{\fontspec[Color=red,Variant=5]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\rede}[1]{\fontspec[Color=red,Variant=6]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\redf}[1]{\fontspec[Color=red,Variant=7]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\redg}[1]{\fontspec[Color=red,Variant=8]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\lbl}[1]{\color{lightblue} #1}
\newcommand{\lbla}[1]{\fontspec[Color=lightblue,Variant=2]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\lblb}[1]{\fontspec[Color=lightblue,Variant=3]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\lblc}[1]{\fontspec[Color=lightblue,Variant=4]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\lbld}[1]{\fontspec[Color=lightblue,Variant=5]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\lble}[1]{\fontspec[Color=lightblue,Variant=6]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\lblf}[1]{\fontspec[Color=lightblue,Variant=7]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}
\newcommand{\lblg}[1]{\fontspec[Color=lightblue,Variant=8]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}#1}

\newcommand{\old}[1]{%
\fontspec[Ligatures={Common, Rare}]{Zapfino Extra LT Pro}%
\fontsize{25pt}{30pt}\selectfont #1}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\old
\noindent{\red d}roo{\lbl g}
\noindent{\reda d}roo{\lbla g}
\noindent{\redb d}roo{\lblb g}
\noindent{\redf d}roo{\lblf g}\\[.3cm]
\noindent{\redc d}roo{\lblc g}
\noindent{\redd d}roo{\lbld g}
\noindent{\rede d}roo{\lble g}
\noindent{\redg d}roo{\lblg g}\\[.2cm]
\end{document}
```

PS: This can be written in a more compact way, but I didn't want to diverge that much from the original example.

Comment: With the open Type Version from Linotype you cannot show such effects.

Comment: @Herbert, I updated the answer, there is an example now.

Comment: What version of the otf do you have? Mine is "LinotypeZapfino-One" Version 005.001, and I cannot get such effects.

Comment: @Herbert: Zapfino Extra LT Pro is newer font, it combines the older four Linotype Zapfino fonts with extensive OpenType features, see http://www.twardoch.com/download/typotechnica2005_zapfino.pdf